# how to clear one specific value in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know how to clear an entire sharedPreference file. But what if I only want to clear one specific entry such as `"first_name"`? I image there must be a better approach than

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(FIRST_NAME, null).apply();
```

Am I wrong about that?

Comment: No that is completely fine. But I would put "" instead of a null as null is not a String to begin with. But you might want to look in the preferences.xml file to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(yourKey).commit();
```

Comment: An explanation might help.

Comment: pretty self explanatory in fairness